# What are susy transformations for N=2 sugra?

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, spinors, supergravity

Killing spinor equations are equations that result from supersymmetric transformations. One example of those is for example is in $N=2$ Supergravity theories.

As suggested by some books and papers on the web, there is the vanishing of the gravitini supersymmetry.

So if fermions here should vanish in $N=2$ supergravity theories, what KSE's should we see in $N=2$ sugra?

Comment: Which books and papers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to find a background preserving some supersymmetry then by assuming that fermions vanish, we have to find a combination of the bosonic fields such that
the supersymmetry variation of the fermionic fields is zero. It means that **all** supersymmetry variations of fermions are required to vanish, not only gaugino or gravitino.

I am not very familiar with $N=2,D=4$ SUGRA, but it seems like in this case the variations are the first, third and forth line in eq (9.46)  http://itf.fys.kuleuven.be/~toine/LectParis.pdf They are respectively the variations of gravitino, gaugino and hyperino.

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics On the top of the page 8 he says "As we neglect here the hypermultiplets, we have to consider the basic supergravity multiplet and the vector multiplets", so I guess in your paper he just considers the simplified action.

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics It is just a simplification, simplifications are always good :)

Comment: I have edited the question to suit the answer you gave and removed the one that has to do with gauginos because I was not convinced that it has to do with hypermltiplets. I'm going to choose this as best answer though. Thank you